# Edge detection and removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, image-processing, edge-detection

I am new to Image Processing. I am developing a web application. I need to take an image (free hand drawings) and remove parts of it. For example, take an image of cat and remove everything except its eye.

P.S-> I am developing a pictionary game based authentication system. It requires user to select an image co-relating his password, and I would morph it by detecting the edges and removing the parts of it and store it as a cue and display it to him, so that it makes sense only to him and not an attacker.

Comment: In other words, like an eraser operated by the mouse pointer?

Comment: Yes, this could be helpful for removal of parts of it. Firstly an edge detection is required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have the entire code, but I had done edge detection using the approach defined [here] (http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/edges2/). The removal of the parts was done using canvas methods

Answer (score 0):

Edge detection is done via a process called Convolution. There are various convolution matrixes defined, one of which is edge detection. You're going to have to look all that up, and also how to do convolution in Java: see java.awt.image.ConvolveOp for a start. How you then remove 'everything except' is another question.

Comment: Thanks EJP. I shall look into ConvolveOp and revert back.

Comment: An "edge detecting" convolution filter is alone pretty much useless on real images. It is actually just the derivative of the image, and highly sensitive to noise, to the brightness of the image and a lot of other factors. Another problem is, that it only detects horizontal and vertical edges, all others will be even more messy. I would recommend a more sophisticated algorithm, for example you can find an implementation for the Canny edge detector in both opencv and Matlab.

Comment: I have done the edge detection part on the client using JS. Now I need to selectively remove parts of the edge-detected image. This also needs to be done using the JS only. Could you please help?

Comment: @Mayank can you post your client js solution in an answer? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have the code with me now, however, I had done it following the approach defined [here](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/edges2/)