# Edge detection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I have a matrix (here's the plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eofSm.png) and I'd like find out, where the edges are.

Here's a picture of the same plot with lines which indicate the edges: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIR2G.png

Is there any algorithm to detect these edges?

Answer (score 6):

There are plenty of fairly simple edge detection algorithms that aren't too hard to implement, such as the [Canny edge detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector). Bear in mind that a lot of these algorithms have different strengths and weaknesses, so I'd suggest you read up on the different approaches and decide based on what you're trying to do.

Alternatively, if you only want the functionality and aren't interested in actually implementing it, you can use the [Pixtastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/edges/) image processing library.

Also, possible [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542871/edge-detection-and-removal) here (though that question is more to do with background removal).

Comment: Thank you for your post. But I don't need a library that does image processing. I think this is more a mathematical problem as i have x-y coordinates than a image problem

Comment: An image is a matrix. Your problem is very well solved using the techniques Alex pointed out.

Comment: @user972654 as kigurai said, edge detection algorithms work because images are represented as matrices of integers (e.g., 0 and 1s for pure black and white, 4 values 0-255 for RGB + alpha images). You'll want to find where edges cross each other (i.e., where there's a change in direction/gradient)